# Most recent Sunday date in yyyymmdd format in ssis expression builder

Tags: ssis

How to get the Most recent Sunday date in yyyymmdd format in ssis? Apply some formulas in SQL actually get me what I need. However in ssis It seems like something different. Any Advice?

Comment: Using the expressions in SSIS is indeed different. However, you can use SQL Statements in your OLE DB connection too (if your source is SQL Server of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this exercise: assuming that consider the date of the current day and check out on the day of the week, then move the day at the **most** recent Sunday. 
 First you need to introduce a variable for the current day of week (@[User::DayOfWeek] int32; Sunday = 1) and calculates how many days you have to go back for Sunday:

@[User::DayOfWeek]

```
DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 1 ? 0 
: DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 2 ? -1 
: DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 3 ? -2 
: DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 4 ? -3 
: DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 5 ? -4 
: DATEPART( "dw", getdate() ) == 6 ? -5 : -6
```

So the expression you need is (taking away the days to return to Sunday):

```
(DT_WSTR,4) YEAR(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate()  )) + 
RIGHT(  "0" + (DT_WSTR,2) MONTH(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() ) ),2) + 
RIGHT(  "0" + (DT_WSTR,2)  DAY(DATEADD( "DD", @[User::DayOfWeek], getdate() )),2)
```

this is the result for 2017-02-10:

```
20170205
```

I hope this help you.